# Ensure cleanup code runs in an async QUnit context

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, tdd, qunit

I am trying to understand how to implement clean-up code after a QUnit test which involves an event being triggered asynchronously.

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23479908/595305). But for one thing, try as I might, I don't understand how I can apply this to my case, and secondly it is using the "old" QUnit approach to async handling (`start` and `stop`...).

Say I have the following test, which is trying to verify that something happens when the `innerText` of a page element changes, triggering a mutation event on a MutationObserver:

```
QUnit.test( 'when the mutation observer reacts ... do something',
    function( assert ){
        console.log( `---------------\nrunning: ${assert.test.testName}\n---------------` );

        try{
            // switch on the MutationObserver...
            Global.dbCompObserver.observe( document, Global.dbCompObserver.config );

            const compX = document.createElement( 'DIV' );
            // by appending it to the body, since the MutationObserver is observing things
            // which happen in the document, a change to the comp will trigger a mutation event
            document.body.appendChild( compX );

            const udv = new UDV();
                
            const done = assert.async();
            udv.update = function(){
                done();
                assert.ok( true );
                // cleanup code... if udv.update is actually called...
                Global.dbCompObserver.disconnect();
                document.body.removeChild( compX );
            };
            assert.expect( 1 );
            // this triggers a MutationEvent... but that function call is async
   *         compX.innerText = 'some new text';
            //

        }finally {
            /* this is where I usually put my cleanup code, with simpler tests
... but I have no idea how to implement cleanup code if, for example, udv.update fails to be called...
            */
        }
});
```

If the "mock" `update` method above is called the clean-up happens... but how to clean up otherwise? You can't put the clean-up code in the `finally` block because that will result in failure of the test: the MutationObserver would be switched off immediately after setting `comp.innerText`, and before the asynchronous mutation event actually ran.

Comment: I'd probably put that test in a module, then in that module use [a `testDone` callback](https://api.qunitjs.com/callbacks/QUnit.testDone/) for doing the cleanup.

Comment: Also, you need to move your `done()` call until after your assertions, otherwise the `testDone` callback will occur before your assertions.

Comment: @JordanKasper thanks, your observations were helpful in understanding how to think through this sort of problem...